# Why doesn't this try and catch work in this case?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning Node.js but cannot understand why this is not working. What is the problem? Thanks for an answer.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

try {
    fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '/test'), {}, err => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err) throw err
    })
}
catch (err) {
    console.log('file is already created')
}
```

This is the result:

> Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'c:\Users\stefa\Desktop\programming\learning-node\playground\paths\test'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PsychoX said, the callback is called **asynchronously**.

You have a few choices:

1. Just use the callback
2. Use the [promises-based fs API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) (or use `util.promisify` on `mkdir`, but...)
3. *(Not recommended)* Use the Sync versoin of `mkdir` (`mkdirSync`)

Here's #1:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '/test'), {}, err => {
    if (err) {
       console.log('file is already created')
       return
    }
    // Do the next thing here
})
```

Here's #2, using [`fsPromises.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options):

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')

fsp.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '/test'))
.then(() => {
    // Do the next thing here
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log('file is already created')
})
```

or within an `async` function:

```
try {
    await fsp.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '/test'))
    // Do the next thing here
} catch (err) {
   console.log('file is already created')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Callback created by lambda expression of `err => {/**/}` is ran asynchronously. `try-catch` cannot catch that.

You should use `Promise`s/`Future`s or synchronized version of `fs.mkdir` function, [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options).

Try something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

try {
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '/test'));
}
catch (err) {
    console.log('file is already created')
}
```

or

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');
const mkdirPromisifed = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);

(async() {
    // ... all other code also should be written in async manner ...
    try {
        await mkdirPromisifed(path.join(__dirname, '/test'));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('file is already created')
    }
}());
```

Comment: Don't recommend `Sync` I/O operations. Instead, show doing this correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am adding answer as fast as possible, then I am adding examples or more detailed description for new-comers.

Comment: `mkdirSynced` would is a misleading name for the function, as the promise version would be an async function.

Comment: Better to use the [promise-enabled fs api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) anyway, as [I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56724124/157247).